# Digest a message and best encoding from byte[] to String

Tags: c#, .net, bouncycastle, digest

**Situation**

I am using Bouncy Castle API in my C# project. I need to hash a `String` using `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto`

**My Sample**

```
String msg = "Message to Hash"; 
MD5Digest dig = new MD5Digest(); 

byte[] msgBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
dig.BlockUpdate(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
byte[] result = new byte[dig.GetDigestSize()]; 
dig.DoFinal(result, 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(result));
```

As as result i got a hash looking like `XasdDdflk7ghXi8azuhe==`

**Questions**

1. I got always the "==" in the end of any different message. Is it normal ?
2. I tried to convert from `byte[]` to `String` using `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString()` but I get symbols like "!?..." I want to avoid the "==" in the end. What should I do ? changing Encoder ?

Comment: I use SHA-1 for my hash algorithm and it also puts those == at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` is a result of base 64 [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) the result.  You can strip them if you so desire.

Comment: I didn't say extra characters.  I said padding.  base64-encoding a string can result in the padded result.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a hex representation of the digest and not a base64 one.

```
return BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", string.Empty);
```

And you will end up with:

```
b3b438c3b84574bb4069e0d667a18503f82fedb5
```